# Can't read json file using cordova/typescrypt on Android

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, typescript

I created cordova project in VS2015
In this project I use PthaseJS for create my game
If I use web emulator all work OK
But if i deploy app on my phone
I can't read json file, other files read OK (example image)
my code simple

```
this.game.load.json('level', "level.json");
```

also I try other code

```
    request.open('GET', 'testlevel.json', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
    request.send(null);

    if (request.status === 200) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
    else {
        alert(request.status);
    }
```

for image it's worked good, for json file return status == 0
I check apk file and see my json file inside

**Update:**
The next day, the problem is not reproduced
I do not know why it occurred,
but I have not changed anything

Comment: When you use dev tools, do you see anything?

Comment: No errors, warning in javascript output

Comment: Do you see the network request in devtools?